# Should [geoip] and [ip-geolocation] be merged?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

Tag description for [geoip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geoip):

> GeoIP is the process of analyzing an IP address and determining the geographical location of that end point.

Tag description for [ip-geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ip-geolocation):

> IP Geolocation refers to services or APIs that provide the capability to locate an address by an IP address.

The two tags seem remarkably similar in both their average usage and tag wiki descriptions.

**Should [geoip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geoip) and [ip-geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ip-geolocation) be merged?**